# using sed "r" to search for text and append contents of file

Tags: sed, string-substitution

I'm reasonably well versed in using sed's inline function, along with it's ability to substitute as well as using different characters as the delimiter for it's functions, but I've now found myself using the "r" function to add the contents of an append file after sed's found a string in a target file. I believe this is called a "zero- or one- address" command.

Quite simply, if a file called "letters" contains

```
abc
def
ghi
```

and the "numbers" contains

```
123
```

Then using

```
sed -i "def r numbers" letters
```

results in "letters" becoming

```
abc
def
123
ghi
```

So, my question is: what happens if "letters" contains forward slashes? As an example, letters2 contains:

```
/abc/def/ghi
/def/ghi/jkl
/ghi/jkl/mno
```

and I want to append "numbers" after the "/def/ghi/jkl" string?  One initially thinks that a simple

```
sed -i '/def/ghi/jkl r numbers' letters2
```

would suffice, but of course with the forward slashes, it makes things somewhat more complicated, considering that this results in an "extra characters after command" error. It would appear that in this instance, you can't denote the symbol as you would in (for example) the substitution side of things.  I've tried (in a number of different ways) things like:

```
sed -i '@/def/ghi/jkl@ r numbers' letters2
```

but I keep on getting the "unknown command: @" error.

I can't find anything online, nor in the manual on how to overcome this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `r` command can be preceded by zero or one address.

From the [documentation of `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses):

> **Sed Addresses**
>
> An address is not required, but if specified must be a number (that counts input lines cumulatively across input files), a dollar (`'$'`) character that
>    addresses the last line of input, or a context address (which consists of a regular expression preceded and followed by a delimiter).

Your examples do not use a number or `$` as the address specifier. The only remaining option is a regular expression enclosed in delimiters. The default delimiter for `regex` in `sed` is the forward slash (`/`).

Since `/` is the `regex` delimiter, any usage of `/` inside the `regex` needs to be escaped (i.e. preceded by `\`).
The command you need is:

```
sed -i '/\/def\/ghi\/jkl/ r numbers' letters2
```

To use a different delimiter for the regex (to avoid the need to escape the forward slashes) you have to prefix it with a backslash when it is used as an open delimiter (before the address). Do not escape it when it is used after the `regex`. Escaping it inside the `regex` tells `sed` to use its literal meaning.

The command in this case is:

```
sed -i '\@/def/ghi/jkl@ r numbers' letters2
```

---

The example you claim is working (`sed -i "def r numbers" letters`) doesn't follow this pattern and it actually doesn't work (at least on the macOS `sed` I am using).
It should be `sed -i "/def/ r numbers" letters` or, to make it more precise, `sed -i "/^def$/ r numbers" letters`.

Answer (score 0):

sed is great for s/old/new but for anything else just use awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{new=new $0 ORS; next} {print} $0=="/def/ghi/jkl"{printf "%s", new}' numbers letters
/abc/def/ghi
/def/ghi/jkl
123
/ghi/jkl/mno
```

The above will work in any awk in any shell on any UNIX box for any contents of any of your input files. It just creates a variable named "new" by reading `numbers` one line at a time and concatenating, then reads `letters` and prints the current line, then prints the contents of `new` if the current line is the string you're interested in.